# What is the name of the particular UI Pattern to switch between previous and next items in a table

Tags: previous, next

I'm working on a system (image is not mine) where users can browse through their items in a table, and click on an item to open a more detailed view. From this detailed view it is not possible to click on another item in the table without also closing the detailed view. That is why we're adding the "previous" and "next" buttons so that the user can browse through the items in the table by going back and forth one item at a time, see image below for more context.

It's often used in caller/lead follow-up systems and is supposed to make the flow of the user a lot more productive/efficient by giving the option to go to the "next" item in the table with a single click, without having to go back to the table, find the "next" item in the table and click.

I'm looking for more inspiration for this type of feature, but realized while searching that I don't really know what this kind of feature is called. Is there a specific name for this kind of UI Pattern?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS there's a similar function to preview various elements from the finder called **QuickLook** *([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look))*.

After selecting the items, pressing the spacebar key displays a preview window with a button bar at the top with various actions such as see next and previous which shows the preview from one item to another without needing to close the window.

[image]

[image]

<sub>*Images from [dummies.com](https://www.dummies.com/computers/macs/mac-operating-systems/how-to-use-quick-look-on-macos-mojave/)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The overarching pattern of these UIs is often referred to as a "Master/Detail Flow", see e.g. http://devguis.com/52-an-android-studio-master-detail-flow-tutorial-android-studio-3-6-development-essentials-java-edition.html

Within that, I was not able to find a dedicated name for the navigational pattern you are interested in other than calling them "Next"- and "Previous"-Buttons.

Another example of where the pattern occurs is in the mail app on iOS when viewing a single message:

[image: Example of next/prev buttons in iOS mail, from osxdaily.com]